# Why BinaryCrossentropy as loss and metrics are not identical in classifier training using tf.keras (Tensorflow 2.0)?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am using BinaryCrossentropy as both a loss and one of the metrics:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5), 
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(), tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

Since they are the same thing, I think they should produce the same result. **However they shows slightly different values on both training set and validation set respectively. Why is this? Shouldn't BinaryCrossentropy has the same value on the same data?**
[image]

Is it possible that, the loss value is the loss on the final batch, and the metric value is calculated on all batches of the epoch (average?)?

I tried to find relevant information on [tf.keras.Model.compile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile), but I couldn't confirm this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same function as the loss and a metric, you will see different  results usually in a deep networks. This is generally just due to `floating point precision errors`: even though the mathematical equations are equivalent, the operations are not run in the same order, which can lead to small differences.

If you consider the simple example for both, it will return the same result.

**BinaryCrossentropy as Metrics:**

```
m.update_state([[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]])
m.result().numpy()
```

> 0.81492424

**BinaryCrossentropy as Loss:**

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [0., 0.]]
y_pred = [[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]]
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
bce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

> 0.81492424

Coming to the calculation for both on each batch and Epoch there is no diffrence in calculation, but there is a difference between the calculation on training dataset and on validation dataset. For the val set the it is calculated at epoch end for your whole val dataset. For the train set: It is calculated on batch end and the average keeps getting updated till epochs end.

The calculation approach changes for metrics and loss only when using sample weights, there's more than just precision errors, which in your case you are not defining any sample weights like below, else it would have been more than the floating point precision error:

```
sample_weight = np.random.rand(len(y_train))
history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=2, sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

- The loss since the start of the epoch is the mean of all batch losses
  seen so far. Each batch loss is the sum of the weighted instance
  losses divided by the batch size (not the sum of weights, so the
  batch loss is not the weighted mean of the losses).
- the metric since the start of the epoch is equal to the sum of
  weighted instance losses divided by sum of all weights seen so far.
  In other words, it is the weighted mean of all the instance losses.
  Not the same thing. If you do the math, you will find that

  `loss =metric * mean of sample weights (plus some floating point precision error)`

Hope this explains your question, Happy Learning!

Comment: @Tyler傲来国主 -  If I have answered your question, please accept and upvote the answer, Thank you.

Comment: The differences in my example seem to be too much to be due to only precision issues. Do you have any references on the *floating point precision errors* or their different ways of calculation? I have not specially assigned any weights to the instances, therefore they should be equally important.

Comment: @Tyler傲来国主 - You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/12_custom_models_and_training_with_tensorflow.ipynb) , in the book written by Ageron  and go to section metrics, you will find the reference.